# No value given for one or more required parameters. vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

Well, I've rooted around the previously asked questions, changed my code three or four times and still am unable to get the form I'm working on to insert data into my table.  Looking for helpful suggestions.

Form code:

```
<div>
    <table align="center" width="200px" cellpadding="5px">
        <tr><td width="50px">Season:</td><td width="150px">
            <asp:DropDownList name="Season" ID="ddlSeason" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Season" DataValueField="Season">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SeasonConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SeasonConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T_Season] ORDER BY [Season]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Game: </td><td>
            <asp:DropDownList name="Game" ID="ddlGameNumber" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Game" DataValueField="Game">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GameNumberConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GameNumberConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T_GameNumbers] ORDER BY [Game]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Team: </td><td>
            <asp:DropDownList name="Team" ID="ddlTeam" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="122px" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Team" DataValueField="Team">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TeamConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TeamConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [T_Teams] ORDER BY [Team]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Player: </td><td>
            <asp:DropDownList name="Player" ID="ddlPlayer" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="121px" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="Player" DataValueField="Player">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PlayerConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PlayerConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Team], [Player] FROM [T_Passing] WHERE (([Season] = ?) AND ([Team] = ?)) ORDER BY [Player]">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSeason" Name="Season" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlTeam" Name="Team" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Atts: </td><td>
            <asp:DropDownList name="Atts" ID="ddlAtts" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" DataTextField="Game" DataValueField="Game">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AttsConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AttsConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T_Atts] ORDER BY [Game]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Comps: </td><td>
            <asp:DropDownList name="Comps" ID="ddlComps" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataTextField="Comps" DataValueField="Comps">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CompletionsConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CompletionsConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T_Comps] ORDER BY [Comps]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Yards: </td><td>
            <asp:TextBox name="Yards" ID="txtYards" runat="server" Width="68px" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>TDs: </td><td>
            <asp:DropDownList name="TDs" ID="ddlTDs" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7" DataTextField="TDs" DataValueField="TDs">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource7" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TDConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TDConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T_TDs] ORDER BY [TDs]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ints: </td><td>
            <asp:DropDownList name="Ints" ID="ddlInts" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8" DataTextField="Ints" DataValueField="Ints">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IntsConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IntsConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T_Ints] ORDER BY [Ints]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Long: </td><td>
            <asp:TextBox name="Longest" ID="txtLongest" runat="server" Width="67px" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
            </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim season As String = Request.Form("Season")
    Dim game As String = Request.Form("Game")
    Dim team As String = Request.Form("Team")
    Dim player As String = Request.Form("Player")
    Dim atts As String = Request.Form("Atts")
    Dim comps As String = Request.Form("Comps")
    Dim yards As String = Request.Form("Yards")
    Dim tds As String = Request.Form("TDs")
    Dim ints As String = Request.Form("Ints")
    Dim longest As String = Request.Form("Longest")

    Dim objConnection As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim objcmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing

    Dim sqlString As String
    Dim dbconn As OleDbConnection = Nothing

    dbconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TCFLStatistics.accdb"))
    dbconn.Open()

    sqlString = "Insert into T_Passing (Season, Game, Team, Player, Atts, Comps, Yards, TDs, INTs, Longest) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    objcmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, dbconn)
    objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Season", ddlSeason.SelectedValue.ToString)
    objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Game", ddlGameNumber.SelectedValue.ToString)
    objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team", ddlTeam.SelectedValue.ToString)
    objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Player", ddlPlayer.SelectedValue.ToString)
    objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Atts", ddlAtts.SelectedValue.ToString)
    objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comps", ddlComps.SelectedValue.ToString)
    objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yards", txtYards.Text)
    objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TDs", ddlTDs.SelectedValue.ToString)
    objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INTs", ddlInts.SelectedValue.ToString)
    objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longest", txtLongest.Text)
    objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    dbconn.Close()
    MsgBox("Record submitted successfully!")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question!

As I continued to scroll through numerous similar questions one person suggested using a Response.Write command to show the sql string to make sure it looked correct.  I inserted a Response.Write command to show the connection string and the sql string to verify accuracy.  I still got the same error.  Then I had the bright idea of commenting out the submit button code.  I ran the code again and got the same error message.  This told me that the error was not in my submission code.

I moved over to the form portion of code and began commenting out the text boxes and drop down lists one at a time starting at the end.  I found that I had changed a column header in my table AFTER I had made the sqldatasource link in this portion of the code:

```
<asp:DropDownList name="Atts" ID="ddlAtts" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" DataTextField="Game" DataValueField="Game">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AttsConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AttsConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T_Atts] ORDER BY [Game]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Once I changed Game to Atts in all applicable portions of code it worked like a charm!

Thank you to all who took time to read my question, submit an answer or answered one of the many other similar questions which lead me to my solution!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using your parameter names in your query text:

```
sqlString = "Insert into T_Passing (Season, Game, Team, Player, Atts, Comps, Yards, TDs, INTs, Longest) Values (@Season,@Game,@Team,@Player,@Atts,@Comps,@Yards,@TDs,@INTs,@Longest)"
```

Comment: Ok, the only other thing I offer is to check the datatypes of your parameters (currently all string) against the datatypes of the fields in your database.